# How to display Google map programatically by Longitude and Latitude

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, google-maps

I am working on a ASP.Net  project. I have SQL Server Database linked with it. The project has the list of hotels present in the city. A page will show the list of hotels on a gridview. Clicking on a hotel will redirect to another page which show the details of that hotel. I want to display Google map picture or Google street picture of that hotel along with the details on that hotel details page through Longitude and latitude. Each hotel's details will be fetched from the database to show on that page and every hotel's longitude and latitude value is also saved in a column in the database.

How can I display Google map picture or Google street view picture with reference to that Longitude and Latitude value that have came from the database?

Comment: how about starting here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example with jQuery and the google maps javascript API:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(
    $('#map')[0],
    {
        zoom: 50,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.250486, 4.432766),
        mapTypeId: 'terrain',
        streetViewControl: true
    }
);

map.StreetView = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    $('#map')[0], 
    {
        position: map.getCenter(),
        pov: { heading: 0, pitch: 0, zoom: 1 
    }
});​
```

Instead of the hardcoded latitude and longitude, you'd use something like this in your ASP.NET .aspx file:

```
...
zoom: 50,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(
    <%= string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, 
        "{0:0.0000}", YourLatitude) %>,
    <%= string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, 
        "{0:0.0000}", YourLongitude) %>),
mapTypeId: 'terrain',
...
```

[Live demo at JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/UCNXC/2/)  A beach on a sunny day... yum!

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Map Integration</title>    
</head>
<body>

    <div>

       <!-- Google Map [Div]-->
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:auto; height:800px;"></div>
       <!-- END: Google Map [Div]-->

    </div>

    <!--Google Map-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //Load Google-Map on [Page-Load]
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', resetMap());

        function resetMap() {            

            //Google-Map DefaultPosition
            var defaultPostion = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);

            //Set Google-Map properties:
            var mapProperties = {
                center: defaultPostion,
                zoom: 2,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            //Load Google-Map on "googleMap" [div]
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProperties);

            var locations = [
                                ['Tool Tip: Dubai', 25.10789521446838, 55.1819798029785, '<div><p>Dubai is the most populous city and emirate in the United Arab Emirates (UAE), and the second largest emirate by territorial size after the capital, Abu Dhabi.  Dubai is located on the southeast coast of the Persian Gulf and is one of the seven emirates that make up the country.</p></div>'],
                                ['Tool Tip: Houston', 29.9928829, -95.4859515, '<div><p>Houston is the most populous city in Texas and the fourth most populous city in the United States. According to the 2012 U.S. Census estimates, the city had a population of 2.16 million people within a land area of 599.6 square miles.</p></div>'],
                                ['Tool Tip: London', 51.51121389999999, -0.11982439999997041, '<div><p>London is the capital city of England and the United Kingdom. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p></div>'],
                                ['Tool Tip: Riyadh', 24.7116667, 46.72416670000007, '<div><p>Riyadh is the capital and largest city of Saudi Arabia. It is also the capital of Riyadh Province, and belongs to the historical regions of Najd and Al-Yamama.</p></div>'],
                                ['Tool Tip: Karachi', 24.872769, 67.091738, '<div><p>Karachi is capital of Sindh as well as the largest and most populous metropolitan city of Pakistan and its main seaport and financial centre of the country.</p></div>']
                            ];

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

                var currentToolTip = locations[i][0]
                var currentLatitude = locations[i][1]
                var currentLongitude = locations[i][2]
                var currentContent = locations[i][3]

                var currentPostion = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

                //Add the [Marker] in Google-Map
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: currentPostion,
                    map: map,
                    title: currentToolTip
                });

                //Initialize [Info Window] for each [Marker]
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                //Add Listener for [Marker] "click"
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,currentContent){ 
                return function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(currentContent);
                    infoWindow.open(map,marker);
            };
        })(marker,currentContent)); 


            } 
        }
    </script>
    <!--END: Google Map-->    

</body>
</html>
```